# How to run cloned Django project?

Tags: python, django, git, github, django-admin

I am a junior software engineer and am quite new to Django. I built [this app](https://github.com/allardbrain/instagram_miner) and am working on a README to explain to others how to fork, clone and setup the app on their own machines. I've gotten stuck while trying to re-create the steps.

This is the order in which I've drawn up the steps:

1. Fork and clone the repo
2. Source a virtual environment
3. Pip install requirements.txt
4. Obtain access_token and secret_key and store in secrets.sh
5. Setup a Postgres DB, create user & database
6. Migrate (?) - This is where I get stuck!

I tried migrating the app but there are no migrations to apply.

I tried `django-admin startproject ig_miner_app` . but am getting this error code:

`CommandError: /Users/Erin/Desktop/CodeByEAllard/project/instagram_miner/manage.py already exists, overlaying a project or app into an existing directory won't replace conflicting files`

If I can get this sorted out, I should just be able to run the server like normal, right?

I'm sure I'm missing something (or many things) but don't know what they are. I feel silly because I was obviously able to create the app in the first place, but can't figure out how to explain to someone else to do the same! Does any have suggestions for how to get the server to run?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you running `startproject`? You already have a project! What error are you getting when running `manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I just ran ` startproject ` because I couldn't think of anything else to try. This is the error I get when I run ` python manage.py migrate `: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: Oh yes, virtualenv is definitely activated.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First off, you are getting that error because you are starting a project within the same directory as the cloned project, this directory already contains an app with the name `ig_miner_app` hence the name conflict.

As regards steps to running the project by other users , this should work.

clone the project

```
git clone https://github.com/erinallard/instagram_miner.git
```

create and start a  a virtual environment

```
virtualenv env --no-site-packages

source env/bin/activate
```

Install the project dependencies:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

create a file named "secrets.sh"

`touch secrets.sh` (mac and linux)

obtain a secret from [MiniWebTool](http://www.miniwebtool.com/django-secret-key-generator/) key and add to secrets.sh

```
export SECRET_KEY='<secret_key>'
```

add secrets.sh to .gitignore file

create a postgres db and add the credentials to settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'name',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

then run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

create admin account

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

then

```
python manage.py makemigrations ig_miner_app
```

to makemigrations for the app

then again run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

to start the development server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and open localhost:8000 on your browser to view the app.

I believe this should get the app up and running on others' machines. Let me know if you get stuck on any of these steps so I make edits, if not, you can just use it and add any other relevant info I might not have added.

Comment: Thanks Bernard! I never created a superuser! I'm going to try this fix right now and let you know how it goes. :-)

Comment: THANK YOU, Bernard! It worked! I am deeply grateful for your detailed help.

Comment: Hi @BernardParah! First of all, thanks for the great explanation. I have one doubt though: you say you need to create a postgres db, but if the project that is cloned already has a postgres db in place and configured into settings.py, do you need still need to do it? Isn't it enough to make sure the new computer has postgresql installed on the machine? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Giulia. If the project already has the db settings configured, you will still need to create the database with the same credentials used in the settings. It's not enough for the computer to have it installed. The only way I know that can happen is if you use a db like sqlite.

Comment: when code is deployed, the contents of the db are not pushed, only the schema of the tables which is in the migrations folder

Comment: @BernardParah this makes sense. Thank you for explaining, I'll get the process done now.

Comment: I suppose I could perfectly create the virtual environment before cloning the project? This is my natural setup

To setup a cloned project from github
1. Create a virtual environment and activate it
2. Install django and all needed packages
3. Clone the repository with 
git clone https://github.com/<username>/<forked-repo>
4. Setup the databse
5. Put database info in settings.py
6. Generate a new secret key, you could use https://djecrety.ir
7. Rename the project, that is the directory that contains settings.py
8. Make your migrations
9. Create a new superuser
10. Final checks

Answer (score 1):

While my hope is that this issue has been resolved by now, if I may, let's revisit something real quick-- I'm sure others have made and, are currently making this mistake.

> I tried 'django-admin startproject ig_miner_app . but am getting this error code:
> "CommandError: " yadda yadda yadda ...

Django actually has amazing documentation. The guys behind it were writers and journalists and not your typical CS guys.

When learning something new, read the documentation. Run through the to-do app tutorial. Here's why:

```
django-admin startproject
```

This has already been satisfied if you are pulling a working copy of a pre-existing Application. Your concern should be with this file first and foremost: `requirements.txt`. This is where the devDependencies state their demands, if you will, similar to `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the app name to the `migrate` command:

```
manage.py migrate ig_miner_app
```

Comment: This is the error message I get when I try to do that:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management

Answer (score 0):

As you said, once you clone the repo, you have to install the requirements

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After that you have to configure the database. Add the details to settings.py

Once it has been done and you have the keys and secrets, you have to make migrations and then migrate.

cd into the app directory and run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

to create migration files for the models already defined in the codes you have cloned. after that you have to run

```
python manage.py migrate
```

to apply the migrations which in effect creates the database tables.

Now you make any changes in models or add extra models or fields, you have to run the last two commands again.

Answer (score 0):

My IDE seems to auto-activate a venv if it resides inside the project directory which caused me to continually run into the error when I cloned from git.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ''`

I had to manually delete the original venv and create a new virtual env then ran these commands. Worked like a PyCharm after :)

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

`python manage.py collectstatic`

Answer (score 0):

1. Create virtualenv and activate it.
2. Install all dependencies.
3. cd into the project's home directory.
4. run $ python manage.py runserver.

Comment: This seems a lot like the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37094453/6243352), except without the commands or any details or motivating explanations...

Answer (score -1):

I take the following steps after cloning the project from GitHub:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject <mysite>
python manage.py startapp polls 
python manage.py runserver
on terminal: python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate
```

These work fine on my system.

Comment: why would you run `startproject` and `startapp` on a cloned project which is supposed to have already both?