# How to run Django server in local system as https using python manage.py runserver command

Tags: django, https

I don't know much about how django works but I am interested in fixing a issue I found in open source project because I can write python code.

I cloned the project and followed the steps as mentioned in this answer: [how to run cloned django project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094032/how-to-run-cloned-django-project/37094453#37094453) and I am able to run the project locally with the command:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and it is successfully running on `http` but I need to run application on `https` as it is integrated with salesforce application and salesforce not allowing `http` as callback.

I have googled on how to run django on https but all I am seeing is how to run django https on `nginx`. I think I need to use library like [letsencrypt.org](http://letsencrypt.org) but not sure how to do that.

Here is the Github project I am trying to work on : https://github.com/benedwards44/packagebuilder

Comment: python manage.py runserver will run local server as localhost and some port. You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023126/how-can-i-test-https-connections-with-django-as-easily-as-i-can-non-https-connec. i basically use django-sslserver

Comment: I'm sure you're aware that you cannot use `manage.py runserver` in production (you'll have to use a real webserver, like nginx). During development, the easiest way to get a https endpoint that connects with your localhost instance is to use ngrok (ngrok.com).

Comment: @thebjorn `ngrok` looks very simple and I got it working. Thank you so much for pointing to me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your project over `https`, I recommend using [ngrok.io](https://ngrok.com/). Use can use something like this from the terminal - `ngrok http 8000`. It will give you a `https` url that will tunnel into your app.