# Django: ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt

Tags: django, pip, requirements.txt

I was following the advices stated here [How to run cloned Django project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094032/how-to-run-cloned-django-project) because I have to work on a cloned Django project.

The steps I followed are:

1. Clone
2. Create and start a virtual environment
3. Install the project dependencies

And here is when I get the following error after running  `pip install -r requirements.txt` :

```
Collecting django-private-chat==0.3.0
  Using cached django_private_chat-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-polymorphic to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-parler to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-mptt to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-model-utils to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-meta-mixin to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-meta to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-loginas to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-js-asset to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-ipware to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-infinite-scroll-pagination to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-imagekit to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-haystack to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-formtools to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-floppyforms to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-filter to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-filer to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-djconfig to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-debug-toolbar-template-timings to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-debug-toolbar to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-countries to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-cms to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-classy-tags to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-braces to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-boto to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-bootstrap-form to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-axes to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-appdata to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django-appconf to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of django to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of dj-database-url to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of defusedxml to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cryptography to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of coverage to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of click to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of chardet to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of cffi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of certifi to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of boto to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of beautifulsoup4 to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of backports-shutil-get-terminal-size to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of <Python from Requires-Python> to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of attrs to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of asn1crypto to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
INFO: pip is looking at multiple versions of asgiref to determine which version is compatible with other requirements. This could take a while.
ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 44) and websockets==7.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    The user requested websockets==7.0
    django-private-chat 0.3.0 depends on websockets==8.1

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Following the pip documentation https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies I installed websockets==8.1, but it didn’t fix the error.

What can I do? I don’t know how to "remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict".
Am I forgetting any essential step while after cloning?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your shoes I would troubleshoot this by creating a fresh virtualenv. Ensure that it is using the correct python version. Then go to the working installation and do a `pip freeze`.  Make sure that the versions of each package in the `pip freeze` match the versions in requirements.txt.  I don't know if that will make it work but it's worth checking on.

Comment: Have you tried removing the requirement for websockets from the requirements.txt file altogether? Any requirements in the file for whichever package is calling it would be installed automatically with the correct dependencies and then you wouldn't have version conflicts by explicitly setting them.

Comment: So, basically I could remove any package from the requirements.txt when its generating a conflict? Because I did what you suggested. Removed the websockets, and now I have the same situation but with others. I will try removing every package that generates conflict then.